# systemd shutdown [1] Failed to wait for process : protocol error

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 Developer version minimal install, on my Asus N750 JK laptop.

When I shutdown Ubuntu this error appears quickly:

```
systemd shutdown [1] Failed to wait for process : protocol error
```

but my laptop still shuts down.

Any idea what is going on? Do I have to worry?

```
$ systemd --version
systemd 237 ....
```

Comment: Is this just once, or is it repeatable?  Also, do you get the same results when you enter `sudo init 0` in terminal?

Comment: Every time I shutdown my laptop. This morning I notice that the message also appears when you reboot.  sudo init 0 in the terminal gives the same result.

Comment: what happens if you logout and change to a terminal ctrl-alt-F3 for instance, login, and put into the commandline **poweroff**

Comment: @abu_bua : When I shutdown my laptop I only have 3 options Cancel / Restart / Poweroff. I click on poweroff and switch on my laptop again. On the login screen I pressed ctrl-alt-F3 and it switch to a terminal screen and there I log in and carry out the poweroff command and the result was : No message appear......  I see that mark already answer the question ......

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

By searching for "[Failed to wait for process: protocol error]", I found there was a [related systemd bug report about it](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8155).

[A fix was merged fairly recently.](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/8429). Perhaps Ubuntu will provide the update in a future update to 18.04.

Comment: This vote puts you over 2000, I see.  I wonder if it will switch to 2k?  Ah, yes, 1999 - a good year.

Comment: @ Mark, any idea how long it will take before Ubuntu will release the bug fix into a new release ?

Comment: @Thuurio No, I have no insider information about that. I recommend contacting Ubuntu developers directly about that.